# how to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}= \infty$ without using Stirling's approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, factorial

In my exam there was this question :

Prove convergence or divergence of :

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}$

I noticed that :

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{4^n 2\pi n \left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2n}{e} \right)^{2n }\sqrt{2\pi (2n)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt{\pi n}= \infty$

I couldn't prove this without using Stirling's approximation

I tried to show that $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1+\frac{n}{k}}{4} \to 0 $ but that was not possible for me

I also tried to use Stolz cesaro theorem but I couldn't show that the limit $\rightarrow \infty$

(all I got was $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}= \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!} \times \frac{4(n+1^2)-1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Quotient-Criterion in a bit more specific form.

With $a_n = \frac{(n!)^2 4^n}{(2n)!}$ you get
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 2\frac{n+1}{2n+1}=1+\frac 1{2n+1}$$

Hence, with $a_1=2$ we get using a telescoping product:
$$a_{n+1} = 2\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac 1{2i+1}\right)$$

Now, we apply the [standard criterion for infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product):

Since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1{2i+1} $ is divergent, so is the corresponding infinite product.

Comment: Your answer does prove that the given sum is divergent, but I think he asked to prove that the "last" term of the sequence $\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @HamLemon
Correct. I extended the answer. It's then easy to show divergence.

Comment: Sorry, I am not well versed in these convergence topics and so I do not understand what you have mentioned in the edited part. Can you kindly give me a briefing or how it can prove that the last term of the sequence $\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: You can avoid infinite products. $${a_n\over a_{n-1}}={2n\over 2n-1}\ge \sqrt{{2n\over 2n-1}{2n+1\over 2n}}= \sqrt{{2n+1\over 2n-1}}$$ Thus $a_n\ge c\sqrt{2n+1}.$

Comment: @HamLemon
I have linked a corresponding page in my answer. Open it and scroll down a bit.

The basic idea behind this convergence criterion goes as follows: 
The given product converges, if and only if the sum of the logarithms converges. But $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$. Further details on the above linked page.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc
So, post your own answer.

Comment: Thanks @trancelocation for the reference, I will try to understand what is given and try to relate it with your post

Answer (score 3):

First we split $(2n)!$ into product of even factors $\cdot$ product of odd factors i.e. : $(2n)! = (2n)(2n-2)..(2) \cdot (2n-1)(2n-3)..(1)$

Now we write $4^n = (2^2)^n = 2^{2n} = 2^n \cdot 2^n$

We multiply both $2^n$ to both $(n!)$ to get $[(2n)(2n-2)..(2)]^2 = (2n)(2n-2)..(2) \cdot (2n)(2n-2)..(2)$

So we have the last term $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n!)^2 \cdot 4^n}{(2n)!} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2n)(2n-2)..(2) \cdot (2n)(2n-2)..(2)}{(2n)(2n-2)..(2) \cdot (2n-1)(2n-3)..(1)} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2n)(2n-2)..(2)}{(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)..(1)}$

Now we have $2n > 2n-1 \;\&\; 2n-2 > 2n-3 \;\&\; 2n-4 > 2n-5 .. 2 > 1$

$\therefore \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2n)(2n-2)..(2)}{(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)..(1)} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n}{2n-1} \cdot \frac{2n-2}{2n-3} \cdot \frac{2n-4}{2n-5} ... \frac{2}{1}$

Since this is a product of infinite terms and all are greater than 1, the product $\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Your idea in last sentence is wrong. The product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+n^{-2})$ has all terms greater than $1$ but it converges.

Comment: Oh, I let that slip through my mind. Sorry for that, can you tell me how to prove that this infinite product $\rightarrow \infty$. I can't seem to justify it now

Comment: My preferred approach for this problem is the one in the answer by user "trancelocation" (which is also the accepted answer as of now).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use $(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!<(2n)!!^2$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$4^n=2^{2n}>{2n\choose n}={(2n)!\over ( n!)^2}$$ Hence $$a_n={4^n(n!)^2\over (2n)!}\ge 1$$ so the series $\sum a_n$ cannot be convergent. Moreover the sequence $a_n$ tends to infinity at the rate $\sqrt{n}.$ Indeed
$${a_n\over a_{n-1}}={2n\over 2n-1}$$ For $n\ge 2$ we have
$$\sqrt{2n\over 2n-1}\sqrt{2n+1\over 2n}\le {2n\over 2n-1}\le \sqrt{2n\over 2n-1}\sqrt{2n-1\over 2n-2}$$ Thus
$$\sqrt{2n+1\over 2n-1}\le {a_n\over a_{n-1}}\le \sqrt{n\over n-1} $$ As $a_1=2$ the latter implies
$$2\sqrt{2n+1}\le a_n\le 2\sqrt{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L(n) :=\frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{L(n)}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}}=4 \sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+n}}$$

By HM-GM inequality

$$\frac{4n}{n-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}} \le \sqrt[n]{L(n)} $$
$$\frac{4}{1-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}} \le \sqrt[n]{L(n)} $$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{L(n)} \ge \frac{4}{1-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx}> 3$$

since $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{L(n)} >1$
there exist $N \in\mathbb{N}$  st $\sqrt[n]{L(n)} >2$ for any $n \ge N$

so $\sqrt[n]{L(n)}>2$ so $L(n)>2^{n}$
letting $n \to \infty $ we obtain:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } L(n) =\infty $$